# Connecting fax to a website

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, fax

I'm building an online file management system for a certain workflow. One of the services of this system should be as follows:
whenever a fax is received, it should be saved in a certain table in the database as a PDF file.
I'm using ASP.NET with C# ..
Is it possible to perform that task without the need for a middle desktop application? 
in case it is possible, explanation of the methodology is greatly appreciated!
thank you!!

Comment: what are you developing, Woof?

Comment: it's an internal system for a university where the website is going to be responsible for all the reporting, file transfer and management issues. The service i'm talking about is where the system will store the received fax messages as a pdf file in a database that is available online to the responsible devision. which means receiving a fax means that it is saved, which will save time and space, prevent data loss and minimize the time of finding old docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of Fax to Email systems available, such as YAC.  If you use one to send an email to your server with the fax attached, you could then use code on your server to save the attachment to a file.  This can be done with Apache and PHP, I can't help you with ASP.NET though.  This might give you a head-start though. http://www.jscape.com/articles/retrieving_email_pop3_csharp.html

Answer (score 2):

To expand on stevenmc's answer, this can be done with ASP.NET on an API-accessible internet fax service such as Interfax.  There are [C# fax samples](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/c) available on their site for review and download.

Once you've signed up for inbound fax service (free for developers), you hook up to the Web Service endpoint from .NET.  The crux of this approach is for your app to query the servers periodically for any new faxes that arrive for you, with method [GetList](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/webservice/reference/getlist):

```
objInterfax.GetList(this.txtUser.Text, this.txtPass.Text, interfax.ListType.NewMessages, i, ref InItems);
```

Any fax sent to your number on their service will appear as a new record in the structure returned by this method.  Once a new fax is available, you download it with method [GetImageChunk](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/webservice/reference/getimagechunk):

```
objInterfax.GetImageChunk(this.txtUser.Text, this.txtPass.Text, InItems[i].MessageID, false, InItems[i].MessageSize, 0, ref b);
```